# how to update existing user table values with password confirmtion in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and going to update My user table values (`name`,`email`,`password`) as the system admin.

**blade** file

```
<form action="{{route('users.update',$user->id)}}" method="POST">
    {{method_field('PUT')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{$user->name}}" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit User</button>
</form>
```

and My controller,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $user = User::findOrFail($id);
  $user->name = $request->name;
  $user->uservalue = $request->uservalue;
  $user->email = $request->email;
  $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
  $user->save();

  return view('users.show')->withUser($user);
}
```

**Problem**

> my password confirmation is not working

That means I can enter password without confirmation and or wrong confirmation password. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you validate your fields?

Comment: NO ....not validate

Comment: Can you post the result of `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in C:\Users\banda\Desktop\acxian\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php on line 118 and defined

Comment: You will have to post a bigger part of your controller. Something is wrong with it but nobody can't tell because we don't have the information. `Request $request` should be a service provider. In your case it's an array. How?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a password confirm validation. For that to work, your second password field has to be called password_confirmation (or foo and foo_confirmation)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $user = User::findOrFail($id);
  $request->validate([
    'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed'
  ]);
  $user->name = $request->name;
  $user->uservalue = $request->uservalue;
  $user->email = $request->email;
  $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
  $user->save();

  return view('users.show')->withUser($user);
}
```

You can add more validation fields as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation). If the validation fails, the browser will bring the user back to the update page. The errors are in the laravel errorbag available in your views as `$errors`.

`sometimes` means that the following rules are needed if there is an input. As you want to update user information, your visitors can leave the password field empty if they don't want to update the password. Unset the password field (if empty) before updating the user input.

Comment: this is occured this error msg * (1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method validate does not exist.*

Comment: Do you `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`? Try `$this->validate($request, ['password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed']);` instead.

Comment: now not error but data not update in the update form.